# Enumerating integer partitions

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

There is a natural way to order all $k=1..p(N)$ partitions of a given integer $N$ ($p(N)$ being a total number of partitions) in a "decreasing" order. Say, for $4$:
$$
\{4\},\,\{3,1\},\,\{2,2\},\,\{2,1,1\},\,\{1,1,1,1\}\,.
$$
(I think, it's pretty clear how the ordering is defined here.)

I'm wondering if there's a known way to reconstruct the partition from its number $k$ in this sequence, and, vice versa, to determine $k$ by looking at the partition?

Comment: If you consider it an easy step to calculate [this quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) then you can do a search (at least a linear search, possibly some form of binary search) based on finding the max element, then recurse down.